# Would like to replace openssl10 with openssl, but it gives me a conflict when using yum install

Tags: openssl, yum

I have openssl10 install in my redhat enterprise 6 server.  I would like to replace it with the latest version of openssl, but yum install fails with several conflicts (see below).  If I uninstall openssl10 before trying to install openssl, then I can't use yum. Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated. BTW, yum replace doesn't work for me.

```
Transaction Check Error:
  file /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.1.0.1e from install of openssl-1.0.1e-16.el6_5.7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package openssl10-libs-1.0.1e-1.ius.el6.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/libssl.so.1.0.1e from install of openssl-1.0.1e-16.el6_5.7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package openssl10-libs-1.0.1e-1.ius.el6.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/openssl/engines/lib4758cca.so from install of openssl-1.0.1e-16.el6_5.7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package openssl10-libs-1.0.1e-1.ius.el6.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/openssl/engines/libaep.so from install of openssl-1.0.1e-16.el6_5.7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package openssl10-libs-1.0.1e-1.ius.el6.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/openssl/engines/libatalla.so from install of openssl-1.0.1e-16.el6_5.7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package openssl10-libs-1.0.1e-1.ius.el6.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/openssl/engines/libcapi.so from install of openssl-1.0.1e-16.el6_5.7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package openssl10-libs-1.0.1e-1.ius.el6.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/openssl/engines/libchil.so from install of openssl-1.0.1e-16.el6_5.7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package openssl10-libs-1.0.1e-1.ius.el6.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/openssl/engines/libcswift.so from install of openssl-1.0.1e-16.el6_5.7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package openssl10-libs-1.0.1e-1.ius.el6.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/openssl/engines/libgmp.so from install of openssl-1.0.1e-16.el6_5.7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package openssl10-libs-1.0.1e-1.ius.el6.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/openssl/engines/libnuron.so from install of openssl-1.0.1e-16.el6_5.7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package openssl10-libs-1.0.1e-1.ius.el6.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/openssl/engines/libpadlock.so from install of openssl-1.0.1e-16.el6_5.7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package openssl10-libs-1.0.1e-1.ius.el6.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/openssl/engines/libsureware.so from install of openssl-1.0.1e-16.el6_5.7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package openssl10-libs-1.0.1e-1.ius.el6.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/openssl/engines/libubsec.so from install of openssl-1.0.1e-16.el6_5.7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package openssl10-libs-1.0.1e-1.ius.el6.x86_64
```

Answer (score 0):

First download the packages and their dependecies and then use the command `rpm`.  With it you can add (`rpm -i`) or remove (`rpm -e`) a package ignoring dependencies using the `--no-deps` option.  Try also to update first (`rpm -U`), we may never know.

Beware this may broke your install, be very cautious, and double-check the dependencies of any package involved.